# Rewrite Anonymous Function for Laravel Upgrade

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upgrade a project that was written in Laravel 5.1 to 5.8. After the upgrade the following code no longer works. How can this be rewritten to work in 5.8?

```
$pf = $this->pageFields->first(function($key, $item) use ($sortOrder) {
  return isset($item->sort_order) && $item->sort_order == $sortOrder;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `where()` function to filter a collection.

```
$pf = $this->pageFields
         ->where('sort_order', $sortOrder)
         ->first();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where